# How to find database or tables in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I cloned a project with git to work on it locally the project is a simple 2 page application one lists the orders made in a shop and the other one let's you edit the selected order it is made using Laravel and it has a `.env.example` file , so i cloned the repo changed `.env.example` to `.env` and used the commands given to me in the readme `composer install`, `php artisan key:generate`,`php artisan migrate --seed`, when the last command in the readme is executed i get this error

what i tried :

1- using mysql i created a database and a user with all privileges to the database
created different tables in the database
2-created a user and gave it all the privileges to all databases

my question in other words how do you find or at least understand if the database is created and how to view the database tables inside the repo not the mysql console (reverse engineering) , where are the sql queries located and the objects we are dealing with

```
                                                                                                                                                                       
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                                 
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1231 Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' (SQL: select * from information_sche  
  ma.tables where table_schema = _db_ and table_name = migrations)                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                       

                                                                                                                                  
  [PDOException]                                                                                                                  
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1231 Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER'
```

mysql output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                                                                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

as you can see there is no `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER`

Answer (score -1):

It's not your project / laravel issue. please go to your database query and execute it. I hope it should save your time.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=''
```

Comment: it didn't show any thing do i have to restart mysql services

Comment: Okay then try one more time by adding NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER manually to your sql_mode variable and see if it works